# How to check input if checkbox is true?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am starting to use Angular JS and I tryng to validate a form. But I don't know how to validate some inputs if the Checkbox is checked.

```
    <body>

<div ng-app="">
  <form name="myForm">
  <input name="myName" ng-model="myName" required>
<span ng-show="myForm.myName.$touched && myForm.myName.$invalid">The name is required.</span><br>
 <input name="myphone" ng-model="myphone"><!--NO REQUIRED--><br>
    Check to Validate:
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="myVar"><br>
    <input type="text"><!--VALIDATE IF checkbox is checked--><br>
    <input type="text"><!--VALIDATE IF checkbox is checked--><br>
</form>  
<input type="submit">
</div>
```

And how to disable the input if something is incorrect?

Comment: what do you mean with validate if checkbox.  what you whant to do with input type text. ? show. hide?

Comment: You do not go to see if _checkbox_ is checked but you set your conditions on `myVar` model (how that's binded to a checkbox or anything else is none of your business)

Comment: @JesusCarrasco I want to validate like the Firts input (with a span next to it) ONLY if the input is checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ng-required`  directive.

```
<div ng-app="">
  <form name="myForm">
  <input name="myName" ng-model="myName" required>
    <span ng-show="myForm.myName.$touched && myForm.myName.$invalid">The name is 
required.</span><br>
     <input name="myphone" ng-model="myphone"><!--NO REQUIRED--><br>
Check to Validate:
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="myVar"><br>
    <input type="text" ng-if="myVar"> <!-- this show ups -->
    <input type="text" ng-required="myVar">
     <span ng-show="myForm.$invalid">
    <input type="text" ng-required="myVar"> 
    <span ng-show="myForm.$invalid">
</form>  
<input type="submit">
</div>
```

**CONTROLLER**

In the controller you can check based on the model asigned

```
$scope.submitFunction = function(){
   if($scope.myVar){
      //do stuff
   }
}
```

Comment: thank! but i dont want to show the input...i want to validate or make it required if the check is checked...

Comment: use the `ng-required` i updte the answer